# mysql stuck on error message for registerusers

Tags: mysql

I'm having some problem with error message that won't disappear and here's my stored procedure of registerusers:

```
DELIMITER go Create procedure registerusers(
   Out UserID tinyint(11),
 IN iFirstName varchar(30),
  IN iLastName varchar(30),
  IN iPassword varchar(30),
  IN iEmailAddress varchar(30),
  IN iSalt varchar(40),
  IN iRoleID varchar(1))
 BEGIN

declare checkfirstnamecount int;
 select count(FirstName) into checkfirstnamecount from users where FirstName = iFirstName;

If(checkfirstnamecount!=1) then SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Fill out the First Name ';

else
     insert into users(      FirstName,  LastName ,  Password ,  EmailAddress ,  Salt ,  RoleID   ) Values ( iFirstName,  iLastName ,  iPassword ,  iEmailAddress ,  iSalt ,  iRoleID  ); set UserID = last_insert_id();    end if;

End go DELIMITER ;
```

when I used:

```
set @new_id = null;
call registerusers(@new_id,'Aaron','James','5566','aaron@gmail.com','sdfd','U');
select @new_id;
```

the error message I got was "

```
MySQL said: Documentation
#1644 - Fill out the First Name "
```

I was intending to pass all the parameters and expecting to work but it didn't. I also tried:

```
 set @new_id = null;
    call registerusers(@new_id,'','James','5566','aaron@gmail.com','sdfd','U');
    select @new_id;
```

the result is the same error message

Comment: I don't understand this logic. "if the name the user provided isn't in the database, tell the user to provide what they already just provided".

Comment: Doing application logic inside the database is really a super bad idea. Try not to go down this path.

Comment: I'm actually doing mysql database not on the php yet. I'm having some problem with logic If(checkfirstnamecount!=1) I thought I would try If(checkfirstnamecount=0) in other words if the first name is not pass then it should go through the error message. but every time I pass  set @new_id = null;
    call registerusers(@new_id,'jamie','James','5566','aaron@gmail.com','sdfd','U'); 
    select @new_id;  I got an error message that says "MySQL said: Documentation
#1644 - Fill out the First Name "